# How do I create a method with a usage pattern like lock?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, methods, locking

How could i create a method like lock in C#

I.e. the pattern for lock is

```
lock(inputParam)
{
   // code here
}
```

I want to create a similar method with a similar usage pattern that internally executes some code before and after code between the brackets,

```
SomeFunc(InputParam)
{
   // Do some stuff
}
```

Is lock a special case in C#, or are we able to achieve similar results with some sort of lambda / action dark magic?

Comment: Would [`using()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) suit your requirements?

Comment: are you asking how to write a function?  What you just described is a function...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

Comment: Its not far off it, however there is a method to my madness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No dark magic. What you want is `try/finally`:

```
DoSomething();
try
{
    // lots of stuff here
}
finally
{
    // do other stuff
}
```

I suppose you could write a method that does it for you:

```
void DoTryFinally(Action start, Action stuff, Action final)
{
    start();
    try
    {
        stuff();
    }
    finally
    {
        final();
    }
}
```

And to call it:

```
DoTryFinally(
    () => { /* start stuff here */ },
    () => { /* stuff here */ },
    () => { /* final stuff here */ });
```

I'd suggest the first way, though: `try/finally` is a common idiom in C#.

By the way, the code you posted:

```
lock (someObject)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Is really just shorthand for what is essentially this:

```
Monitor.Enter(someObject);
try
{
    // do stuff
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(someObject);
}
```

The compiler generates that when it compiles a `lock` statement.

There is no facility built in to the compiler that will let you do that with arbitrary functions. The [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) comes close, but it's not a general solution.

Comment: Thanks, your last example (pattern) is what i have a lot of around my application, and essentially achieving the similar results , see comment to Tims answer, however i thought there was something i could do a bit more elegant than just actions, however i think actions it is

Answer (score 1):

`lock` is only a little special: it is mentioned in the C# Specification, but is equivalent to code you could write (see §8.12 of [the spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)). You can do something vaguely similar:

```
void Main()
{
    SomeFunc(2, () => {
        //do stuff
    });
}
public void SomeFunc(int inputParam, Action body)
{
    //do before stuff
    body();
    // do after stuff
}
```

Such a pattern sounds unusual, however. I'd see if there's a better way to do what I want, before assuming this is a good approach.

Comment: "Such a pattern sounds unusual, however" --- the pattern OP wants to implement is actually the Decorator Pattern (OP decorates a bunch of statements with some another pre- and post-invoked statements). So technically it sounds pretty much usual.

Comment: Basically, i just need to have a reusable pattern, that is essentially a File looking system that uses lock itself, and regulates (registers/unregisteres/ and queriable) access to files (fileNames) in a large application